# zsh error when executing python code as a script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script which uses `sys` to accept arguments -

```
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
```

I need to provide it with a bunch of urls to parse. The script works perfectly on a jupytor notebook (after hard-coding the arguments in the code: `url = 'http://www.hello.com'`) notebook but when I try to execute it as a script I get errors like these, for various URLs -

for 'http://www.blog.example.com:123/path/to/file.html?key1=value1'

```
[1] 85926
zsh: no matches found: http://www.blog.example.com:123/path/to/file.html?key1=value1                                              
[1]  + exit 1    python -m urlparser
```

for 'https://www.hello.com/photo.php?id=2064343443411&set=a.2634433167446&type=3&hall'

```
zsh: parse error near `&'
```

Meanwhile, the script works fine for simpler URLs like `https://blog.hello.com/one/two`

What could be the issue? Encoding problems?

Comment: Quote the arguments you pass with `"`

Answer (score 0):

I figured -

Have to put the arguments in quotes like - `'http://www.blog.example.com:123/path/to/file.html?key1=value1'`